# After concat the page scrolls back to the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items on a page. When I scroll to the bottom there is a "Load more" button. When I click this i get the new items and concat them to the original list:

```
handleLoadProducts = (append = false) => {
    this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
    });

    fetch('/products', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            filters: Object.keys(this.state.filters),
        }),
    }).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => { 
            this.setState({
                products: append ? this.state.products.concat(data.data): data.data,
                isLoading: false,
                hasMore: data.data && data.data.length > 0
            }); 
        })
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e, 'error');
    });
};
```

Then in render I have something like this:

```
<Products products={this.state.products} isLoading={this.state.isLoading}/>
```

However after this, the page scrolls back to the top. Is it possible to prevent this? i.e. stay where you are?

Comment: Are you sure that you set the state once? The behaviour you describe appears if you would set the state to contain no elements, then there is nothing to scroll so the scroll bar gets reset, then you add data and it looks as if it was scrolled to the top.

Comment: Note: I updated the question.
What is weird is when I do a console.log(this.state.products) in render then i see 2 print outs, one with same 10 products and then a second print of the concat with 20 products

Comment: ah figured it out, you were right. When I load more i show a loading state which = no products and then after loading the products are shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that state is only set once:

```
if(!this.state /* && !this.state.products */) {
    this.setState({ products: data });
}
else {
    this.state.products.push(data.data);
}
```

Not sure how the rest of your logic is that's why I added the comment around this.state.products.

Comment: I updated the question with the full logic basically